Why is my RxJs Subject not working as expected?
ProductGalleryComponent.html iterates over products. The click event of each image calls the setSelectedProduct function passing to it the product that was clicked.
<div class="row py-3 px-2" style="background: #f5f6f8">
  <div
    class="col d-flex flex-column col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4 gallery-img-col"
    *ngFor="let product of products"
  >
    <img
      class="gallery-img"
      src="assets/img/{{ product.images[0] }}"
      (click)="setSelectedProduct(product)"
    />
  </div>
</div>

The setSelectedProduct function of ProductGalleryComponent.ts calls the setSelectedPRoduct function of the ProductGalleryService, passing the selected product. It then navigates to the SelectedProductComponent.
public setSelectedProduct = (product: ProductModel) => {
    this.productGalleryService.setSelectedProduct(product);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/selected-product');
  }

ProductGalleryService declares a subject and an observable of the subject. In the setSelecedProduct function, it calls the next function of the subject, passing to it the selected product:
export class ProductGalleryService {
    public selectedProductSubject = new Subject<ProductModel>();
    selectedProductSubject$ = this.selectedProductSubject.asObservable();

    public setSelectedProduct = (product: ProductModel) => {
        this.selectedProductSubject.next(product);
    }
}

The SelectedProductComponent subscribes to the selectedProductSubject of ProductGalleryService via the constructor. It is expected to receive the product broadcast by ProductGalleryService.selectedProductSubject but the product is never received.
export class SelectedProductComponent {        
    private productGalleryService = inject(ProductGalleryService)

    constructor() {
        this.setSelectedProduct()
    }

  private setSelectedProduct = () => {
    this.productGalleryService.selectedProductSubject$.subscribe((product) => {
      this.selectedProduct = product;
      console.log('selectedProductSubject.selectedProduct', this.selectedProduct)
    })
  }
}


I expect to see ProductGalleryService injected in the constructor for SelectedProductComponent. this.productGalleryService.selectedProductSubject$ is probably erroring. Are there any console errors?

@RyanSand20 ProductGalleryService is injected in SelectedProductComponent. There are no console errors.

Could you please provide a stackblitz?

I believe the ProductGalleryService.selectedProductSubject$ subject has already emitted before the SelectedProductComponent subscribes.
How to get around this problem?
RxJS offers another type of Subject - a ReplaySubject.
When subscribing to a ReplaySubject, it will re-emit any previously pushed values.
The ReplaySubject has a buffer size, how many items to store and re-emit. For your use case, I believe you only care about the last one, so BufferSize is 1.
public selectedProductSubject = new ReplaySubject<ProductModel>(1);


Subject vs BehaviourSubject vs ReplaySubject 
How to get current value of RxJS Subject or Observable?


On the money. Thank you.

You could try using the Angular AsyncPipe to handle subscribe/unsubscribe automatically. This is useful for binding Observables to the template.
Instead of:

Create local variable
Subscribe to observable\
On Emit, store emitted value in local variable

You would:

Store the observable as a local variable
Bind to the observable in your template using async pipe

<div *ngIf"selectedProduct$ | async as selectedProduct">
  <h1>{{ selectedProduct.name }}</h1>
</div>

This has the added benefit of automatically unsubscribing. You always want to close subscriptions when your component is destroyed. In your example, this isn't done. This is not your main problem, but something else to look into.

This is another approach, the one I use for everything. You sometimes need to create container & display components to make this ideal. If you can, always use AsyncPipe over the subscribe & store approach.

The issue comes from using a Subject , which does not retain the last emitted value , this means that when the SelectedProductComponent subscribes to selectedProductSubject$ , the event has already been emitted.
To fix this replace Subject with a BehaviorSubject :
  private selectedProductSubject = new BehaviorSubject<ProductModel | null>(null);

To understand the difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject, take a moment to read the answers provided here.
